# How to update changes in child component

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

Child component's `@input` value not updating its value in `html`, as `two-way` binding usually does. Here is my code.

```
parent.component.html

<app-child [i]="selectedMonth" (monthChanged)="monthChanged($event)"></app-child>

monthChanged(d: Date) {
    this.selectedMonth = d; // this is working as expected.
    console.error(this.selectedMonth); // working...
  }

child.component.html

<div>
    <span (click)="addMonth(-1)">Prev </span>
    <span>{{i | date:'MMM-yyyy'}}</span> // this value not being changed.
    <span (click)="addMonth(1)">Next </span>
</div>

child.component.ts

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() i: Date;
  @Output() monthChanged = new EventEmitter<Date>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  addMonth = (m: number) => {
    this.i.setMonth(this.i.getMonth() + m);
    this.monthChanged.emit(this.i);
  }

}
```

What I tried?

```
this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.error(this.i); // no error log...
    this.i = changes.i.currentValue;
    console.error(this.i); // no error log...
  }
```

But none working. What else should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a stackblitz reproducing your problem. You can check it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jaxtqp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

You can check console logs. When you update within child component with `this.i.setMonth(this.i.getMonth() + m)` it also updates `parent`s
`selectedMonth`. Because they are the same object. Since, the object reference does not change, Angular won't run change detection. You can fix this by creating new object within `monthChanged` as follows

Change

```
monthChanged(d: Date) {
  this.selectedMonth = d; 
  ...
}
```

to

```
monthChanged(d: Date) {
  this.selectedMonth = new Date(d); 
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data will be updated when whole reference will be updated. If you just update some properties inside that object, it will not be triggered. You need to change the reference of the passed object.

Example

```
<child [data]="myData"></child>
```

If you will update `myData.test= "YourData",` it will not be triggered. You need to do something

```
this.myData = changedData;
```

A workaround can be using DoCheck lifecycle hook and try to check the property change manually. But generally it is more handy to change the reference.

Check your value over here

```
 // on every change of @input 'name', this method will be triggered

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.data=changedData 
  }
```